# An equivalent of async pipe in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs

I'm using [ng-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) in Ionic2, which provides me with this method for translating strings in the code. Currently, I have to use the service like this:

```
translate.get('ERROR').subscribe((res: string) => {
   //The string with code 'ERROR' is translated in res
   this.errorString = res;
});
....
//Later on, when error happens:
alert(this.errorString);
```

I have a lot of strings, alerts, and notifications in many files. Subscribing to a `get` method's observable for each of them is very tedious. In html, one can easily avoid this buy using the async pipe, or in this case translate pipe, which doesn't require explicit subscription to the observable:

```
<div>{{ 'ERROR' | translate}}</div>
```

Is there any way that I can do this with the same level of simplicity for the strings that are in the typescript file? for example ideally, I would like to have a shorthand to suscribe that achieves this:

```
   alert(idealTranslateFunction('ERROR'));
```

Comment: *"doesn't require explicit subscription to the observable"* - yes it does. *That's what `| async` does!*

Comment: I know that's what `| async` does. As a developer, using that pipe, I don't have to explicitly write the subscribe code. I'm looking for a shorthand like this in the code.

Comment: Well you could write your own `asyncAlert` function that took an observable, for example, there's nothing to stop you doing that. Just extract the common code, like any other refactor.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the code is in `async` function, it can be

```
this.errorString = await translate.get('ERROR').toPromise();
```

Otherwise `subscribe(...)` should be used.

Comment: just wondering, what does `await` do? Will the promise be resolved?

Comment: @Ivaro18 Yes, it will. See more on [async/await](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/async-await.html).